# vba conditional formatting select a rule

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

In an excel you can easily use COnditional FOrmatting> New Rule> under Select a Rule bar you can choose one mode from 6 available. But inside vba you can only use Select cell that contains mode. I need to change it to 6th one, Select custom condition. Is there any possibiliy. Maybe the issue is due to I use percentages?

My code is simple;

```
With ThisWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue,xlGreaterEqual, "=$B3>=100%")
.AppliesTo=Range("A1")
.StopIfTrue=False
    With .Font
    .ColorIndex=4
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

- It's [`FormatConditions.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add) (probably a typo in your question)
- `xlGreaterThan` is not a valid option. Probably you meant `xlGreaterEqual`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlformatconditionoperator) for a list of options.
- `100%` is equivalent to `1`.

```
Dim cond As FormatCondition
Set cond = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3").FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreaterEqual, 1)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use an expression, then:

```
With ThisWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B1>=1")
    .AppliesTo=Range("A1")
    .StopIfTrue=False
     With .Font
        .ColorIndex=4
     End With
End With
```

Comment: Hmm..Interesting. Actually my code works.So how? It adds conditional formats to the cell, but the color does not change. I add with vba three conditions and all are added. I will try as you have mentioned and come back to give feedback. xlGreatOrEqualThan

Comment: Okay, let me bring my code here. Because I add the code With Statememnt

Comment: It's `xlGreaterEqual`, not `xlGreatOrEqualThan`. It may be helpful for you to use the macro recorder.

Comment: I have edited the code, two differences between mine and yours. Dim'ming and Font.Interior

Comment: Change `xlCellValue,xlGreaterEqual, "=$B3>=100%"` to `Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$B1>=1"`